# how can more than one thread have "locked" on the same object (as shown in a thread-dump)

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, thread-dump

I have the following thread-dump, which shows two threads both locking on the same object. And I'm confused as to what it really means

```
    "pool-1-thread-2" prio=10 tid=0x00007fd6dc106000 nid=0x5d15 in Object.wait() [0x00007fd6d2067000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007c3547770> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at test.TestDead$Foo.second(TestDead.java:22)
    at test.TestDead$Foo.first(TestDead.java:14)
    - locked <0x00000007c3547770> (a java.lang.Object)
    at test.TestDead$2.run(TestDead.java:45)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007c35519e8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fd6dc104800 nid=0x5d14 in Object.wait() [0x00007fd6d2168000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007c3547770> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at test.TestDead$Foo.second(TestDead.java:22)
    at test.TestDead$Foo.first(TestDead.java:14)
    - locked <0x00000007c3547770> (a java.lang.Object)
    at test.TestDead$1.run(TestDead.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007c3551730> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

What does "locked" really mean here?

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's exactly the page I read before turning to StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you show the whole stacktraces? Two threads can hold the same lock, if one of them is waiting.

Comment: @Banthar post updated. Could you explain this bit about two threads holding the same lock? I just don't understand. I thought "lock" was supposed to be held by one and only one thread. Thanks

Comment: Since `wait()` is a Native method, my guess is that the fact that `wait()` unlocks the monitor doesn't get reported in the thread-dump.  Thus both threads lock the monitor and call `wait` (which unlocks it internally) but it still shows as locked in the thread-dump.

Answer (score 5):

In this context, *locked* means that your running java code has entered a `synchronous` block but not yet exited that block.

As your thread-dump shows, you are calling `wait()` which *internally* unlocks the monitor associated with the `synchronous` block.  However, since you are blocking on wait and have not exited the synchronous block, the thread-dump still shows `locked`.  Thus it is possible to have multiple threads display `locked` in the thread-dump despite the fact that the underlying monitor is unlocked.

This can be easily demonstrated with a simple test:

```
public class TestMonitor {

    synchronized public void lockAndWait() {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
            // Stifle
        }
    }

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        TestMonitor tm = new TestMonitor();
        tm.lockAndWait();
    }
}
```

which outputs the following thread-dump when run:

`"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f86c4008000 nid=0x5d35 in Object.wait() [0x00007f86cbae2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000759055df8> (a TestMonitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at TestMonitor.lockAndWait(TestMonitor.java:5)
    - locked <0x0000000759055df8> (a TestMonitor)
    at TestMonitor.main(TestMonitor.java:13`

Note the monitor is still `locked` despite being in `wait`.

### UPDATE

In the event the single thread case isn't convincing, you can run the above example slightly modified in which case you'll see multiple threads `locked` on the same monitor in the thread-dump:

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    final TestMonitor tm = new TestMonitor();

    Thread thread1 = new Thread( new Runnable() { public void run() { tm.lockAndWait(); } } );
    Thread thread2 = new Thread( new Runnable() { public void run() { tm.lockAndWait(); } } );
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
```